# Problem with Jar file loading in Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a problem with adding my jar file to the Scene Builder Library. When I click open, nothing shows in the import dialog.

```
private Alert mb;
public FXMLDocumentController() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("/data/Data.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        mb = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    }
```

What I have found out so far is that when I comment "mb = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);" the problem disappears and the jar loads.

**How is the alert affecting all this?**

[image: with alert]

[image: without alert]

Javafx sdk 11, Java jdk 11, Scene Builder 11

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the alert before `fmxlLoader.load()` and see if that works